# Why is a butterfly actively looking for cool, dark spot, long before dark?

Tags: ecology, behaviour, lepidoptera

Here in Croatia, the Woodland grayling *Hipparchia fagi* flies constantly in the garden of my holiday home.
Yesterday, I observed that one of these bufferflies was **actively looking for a cool/dark spot around 6 pm**. First it hid at a wall in a shaded corner behind a bush. During the day these butterflies are very alert, but this specimen could be approached to a few cm. Finally it flew away, to take refuge inside the house, even more cool and dark. Again, it didn't move until I blew it away (couldn't lock it in, could I).

Now, my question is **why this butterfly behaved like this.**

I am convinced it did not seek shelter from the heat, because they keep flying during the hottest part of the day.

Was it already looking for a place to spend the night? That seems rather early. At 6 pm, the sun is going down a bit, but temperature is still around 30 degrees and it won't be dark for 3 or 4 hours. Other butterflies like Iphiclides podalirius are still active. Or has H. fagi a higher heat demand than other species? That seems inconsistent with its habitat (woodland). Any thoughts?